# How to pass environmental variables to downstream from jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am running Jenkins on a windows machine.
How can I pass environment variables like %BUILD_NUMBER% to a downstream job?
I am using below piece of code but that is not working as expected, it is printing the same thing again in output

```
build job: 'DeployBuild', parameters: [string(name: 'BuildId', value: $env:BUILD_NUMBER)], wait: false
```

The output I am getting:

```
C:\JenkinsBuilds\jobs\DeployBuild\workspace>echo $env:BRANCH_NAME-$env:BUILD_NUMBER 
$env:BRANCH_NAME-$env:BUILD_NUMBER
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Expected Output:

```
C:\JenkinsBuilds\jobs\DeployBuild\workspace>echo TESTJob-12
TESTJob-12
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Tried multiple patterns like ${BUILD_NUMBER}, $BUILD_NUMBER %BUILD_NUMBER but none is giving the expected output.

Comment: I had created pipeline in jenkins, simply tried to call `println env.BUILD_NUMBER`, works

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending env.BUILD_NUMBER or "${BUILD_NUMBER}" or "env.BUILD_NUMBER" and notice the double quotes string interpolation happens only for double quotes .

Answer (score 0):

Put the `value: $env:BUILD_NUMBER)` as `value: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}`. This will do it. So total code will be like:

```
build job: 'DeployBuild', parameters: [string(name: 'BuildId', value: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER})], wait: false
```